# Center <h1> with {display: inlineblock;}

Tags: html, css

i found the solution:
i removed `display: inline-block;` because i only got that from this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?66277-border-only-around-text-not-full-container-width

i instead did:

`width: 300px;` because the length of the text is 300px
and then `margin: auto;` worked(it didn't work when i did `display: inline-block;`.) now it the border doesn't
cover too much space and it's centered

thanks everyone that tried to help

---

I want the border to not take up so much unnecessary space, just cover the text.
So i used  `display: inline-block;`.

[what it looks like with `display: inline-block;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKCJP.png)

But it's not centered so i put `margin-left: 550px;` and `margin-right: 550px;`.

[how it looks with margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SLzM.png)

Now it's centered but it breaks when I resize the browser and it might be off-center on different resolution monitors. How do i make it like "1234"(the text under) which can resize itself?

[image of when the browser is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgxEW.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: search for responsive .. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Comment: What do you mean by the "1234" text resizing itself?

Comment: sorry if what im saying doesnt make sense, like i said, im new.
when i resize the browser, the border also changes size.

Comment: If possible please upload your html and css so that you can get exact solution.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you using `inline-block`? Can you show some code?

Answer (score -3):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

add css for margin and may be you need to set width also

Comment: it might work in your condition